# how to contruct route containing # in node express app

Tags: node.js, express, routes

Does anyone know if I have a url such as the following what should be route set in node express app.

```
http://abc.com/fbauth#access_token=<some random number>.
```

So if I put route as "/fbauth" in express/node app then it cannot parse the rest of the url, neither with req.params nor with req.query

any help appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

# is reserved and while valid for a URI it is not submitted in a request to the backend. It is very useful for front end tricks and e.g. page anchors and navigation within single page web apps.

If you need to pass args back then a get request using the ? sign instead of # will pass the access_token to the node app.

Comment: well...this is the trick being used by facebook to return a access_token...without a middle step of supplying a code for their oauth...does it mean that the part of the url beyond # cannot be captured in node express ?

Comment: use `\#` to tell markdown you want to escape the hash instead of making an `<h1>`... also, yes, express never sees anything after the hash. that's how [zerobin](http://sebsauvage.net/paste) ([project page](https://github.com/sebsauvage/ZeroBin)) allows an encrypted pastebin where the server has zero knowledge of the encryption keys.